# Layout para todos os tamanhos de tela

Tags: android, android-layout, layout-responsivo

Comecei a pouco tempo a mexer com android e me surgiu uma grande dúvida. Como eu faço um layout para que funcione em todos os tamanhos de telas?

Pelo que pesquisei, existem pastas específicas de layout para cada tamanho. Então, como eu crio essas pastas, já que no Android Studio vem apenas com uma pasta "layout".

Outra pergunta, feito isso, como o meu aplicativo vai saber qual layout abrir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É só criar as pastas no mesmo nível que a layout e criar o arquivo dentro com o mesmo nome. O Android se encarrega de verificar qual a dimensão da tela e pega o layout na pasta correspondente.
O seu trabalho é só escrever os arquivos de layout para cada dimensão e colocá-los nas pastas certas
O mesmo vale para a pasta `drawable`

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Recomendo que primeiro dê uma lida nesse artigo da google: [Supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).
Tenho certeza que após ler todo esse tutorial (pode tacar no google tradutor mesmo) não irás te restar dúvidas.

Basicamente tens de redimensionar suas imagens para tamanhos pré-definidos pela Google. O Android, por baixo dos panos, escolhe qual o tamanho ideal automaticamente baseado na tela do seu telefone!

Answer (score 0):

Existe algum padrão para o nome das pastas? Desse modo então, o seguinte código é desnecessário? Pois foi o unico modo que eu tinha achado para a solução do meu problema

```
if (config.screenWidthDp  == 720) {
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_720x1280);
 }
```